# No EFI partitions while installing Ubuntu on a USB flash drive

Tags: uefi

I need to install Ubuntu on a USB flash drive. I have Windows 10 installed on the internal SSD. I do not want to install Ubuntu as a dual boot. I just want to install it on the external USB drive. When I attempted to do so, however, after selecting "Something else" and creating a partition on my USB flash drive with selecting "Use as Ext4 journaling file system" and "Mount point /", I received the message that "No EFI partitions are found. Continue at your own risk". I do not know what to do. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: See launchpad bugs 1173457,1396379,1702335.  Simple answer is to create an EFI partition on your USB as well, but it wont be used, and your machine wont boot without the USB without some fixes.  Or, if your machine allows you to select a boot mode preference, so it will boot both without further changes, just do a legacy install (select legacy as preference so install media boots in legacy).

Comment: Can you explain it to me in a more detailed way?